# Qt resize widgets in linear layout with mouse

Tags: c++, qt

I have a linear layout which has 2 widgets, like this,
[image]
The black square is the linear layout, and the blue squares are 2 widgets, `Widget0` and `Widget1`. 
What I want to implement is while dragging the right edge of `Widget0` or the left edge of `Widget1`, both widgets can be resized with mouse.

Does anyone have some simple ways to make it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for QSplitter. See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplitter.html

Example, three resizable text edit (or widget):

```
    QTextEdit *editor1 = new QTextEdit;
    QTextEdit *editor2 = new QTextEdit;
    QTextEdit *editor3 = new QTextEdit;

    QSplitter* splitter = new QSplitter(Qt::Horizontal);
    splitter->addWidget(editor1);
    splitter->addWidget(editor2);
    splitter->addWidget(editor3);
    setCentralWidget(splitter);
```

Results:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Thanks.