# Changing width of QWidget with mouse

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I have two QWidgets inside a QHBoxLayout. I want to be able to change the width of the left QWidget by clicking on its right side and moving mouse (such as the Qt Editor's projects browser).

Comment: I wonder if QSplitter is the widget you are looking for?  It would allow you the user to choose the width of the two widgets by dragging left or right on the drag-bar that is between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do exactly what you want  by using QSplitter. You can find a complete example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38433287/4297146

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eventFilter` and get mouse Move,Enter,Leave and mouse click on a widget.

Check this example:
I made two widget with `QHBoxLayout` and get `QEvent::HoverEnter` and `QEvent::MouseButtonPress` for both.

[image: Example Form]

.cpp file:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    widgetOneW = 300;
    widgetTwoW = 300;

    ui->widgetOne->installEventFilter(this);
    ui->widgetTwo->installEventFilter(this);

    ui->widgetOne->setAttribute(Qt::WA_Hover);
    ui->widgetTwo->setAttribute(Qt::WA_Hover);
}

bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event)
{
    if ((object == ui->widgetOne) && (event->type() == QEvent::HoverEnter))
    {
        ui->widgetOne->resize(100, ui->widgetOne->height());
        ui->widgetTwo->resize(widgetTwoW, ui->widgetTwo->height());
        return true;
    }
    else if ((object == ui->widgetOne) && (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress))
    {
        QMouseEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent *> (event);
        if(keyEvent->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
        {
            ui->widgetOne->resize(100, ui->widgetOne->height());
            ui->widgetTwo->resize(widgetTwoW, ui->widgetTwo->height());
            return true;
        }
    }
    else if ((object == ui->widgetTwo) && (event->type() == QEvent::HoverEnter))
    {
            ui->widgetOne->resize(widgetOneW, ui->widgetOne->height());
            ui->widgetTwo->resize(100, ui->widgetTwo->height());
            return true;
    }
    else if ((object == ui->widgetTwo) && (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress))
    {
        QMouseEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent *> (event);
        if(keyEvent->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
        {
            ui->widgetOne->resize(widgetOneW, ui->widgetOne->height());
            ui->widgetTwo->resize(100, ui->widgetTwo->height());
        }
    }
}


MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

.h file:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QKeyEvent>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

    int widgetOneW;
    int widgetTwoW;

public slots:
    bool eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

.pro file:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = first
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```